# Remote Actions without Remote Desktop?

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-11, remote-control, miracast

I have a Surface Book that I'm trying to use as a semi-sidecar-esque device, without relying on the laginess of Miracast, while retaining touch capabilities, however I am finding it quite clunky to use without almost every action requiring multiple inputs.

My setup is as follows:

- Main PC, connected to network via LAN and controlled with KB & Mouse. 2 monitors
- Surface Book 2, connected to network via Wireless, but can connect to LAN via HUB. Keyboard detached. Controlled via Touch.

Both running W11.

Here's what I am trying to achieve:

- Control Spotify/Audio services on main PC via Surface - Easy with existing features
- Send Browser tabs between machines easily (e.g. a YouTube video, article, etc.) - PITA requiring multiple precise taps, clicks etc on both devices.
- Open files located on main PC, on the Surface (e.g. a PDF, Word Doc, etc.) - Can access via fileshare, but opening the file requires more manual input than I'd like. I.e. I can't go "Open file on Surface Book"
- Use the Surface Book to send commands on the Main PC (e.g. Launch a program)

My first question is: Is something like this even possible without developing an entirely new piece of software

Secondly, if it is, how could I achieve this in a way that isn't going to absolutely tank my performance.

I am open to simple "Use the surface as a third display" options that would allow touch input, but there seems to only be Miracast available for this and Miracast is pretty rubbish. I would also use Remote Desktop but that feels very clunky and doesn't really work with the "third display" type of use-case.

I have some current ideas:

- Chrome Tab sharing: Some form of extension or shortcut that will allow me to do this. Admittedly I have not investigated this thoroughly.
- File Sharing & Automatic Opening: Some form of file "transfer"/share system alongside something like this: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/how-can-i-automatically-open-new-files-added-to-a-folder/
- Sending commands (e.g. open an application): I am unsure on this but I wonder if something with Autohotkey might work or even something like the above with Shortcuts.

Any other ideas or validation of the above being best method welcome.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the answer u want to see.. but it's more like imho version of answer. Here it goes..

1. u have multiple goals. Each can be done by multiple ways. So, can 1 software covers all? Perhaps. (excluding custom-made software).
2. "Remote Actions without Remote Desktop?" is the question. But it is actually just 1 of the 4 goals. If I'm gonna rephrase it : which one (of the 4 goals) is actually the top priority? (referring to that answer) Does it REALLY need 'remote actions' to be delivered via network, or a cloud solution will do?

The above 2 statement is the 1st thing that come to my mind.. when processing this question. What i mean here is, u may need to go for a multiple software/solution to achieve ur 'need' goals. The solution that works last year may not last as a good solution next year. Have a good exploration.. ( :

========================================

This part is my way of doing things. Since I don't have either surface nor Win11 (I use android & Win7-64bit), I cannot vouch that it will work on ur system.

1. "Control Spotify/Audio services on main PC via Surface " <-- I didn't use. Not sure.
2. "Send Browser tabs between machines"

- chrome/opera/firefox can do this if both machine browser logs in the same account. can refer their own documentation on this.
- (my way).. I used to use pastebin.com to pass links/text from a machine to another. But now I somehow prefer disposablechat.com to do that.

3. "Open files located on main PC, on the Surface "

- share a folder in the network, via ftp. i use https://www.pablosoftwaresolutions.com/html/quick__n_easy_ftp_server_lite.html as the server. And any other PC on the same network can just enter "ftp://191.168.1.54" (example addrs) on the explorer, with (optional) password, and they can open/download/upload any file from/to the Main PC. u can also type "ftp 191.168.1.54" in the cmd (command prompt) of the surface, then apply the "ls","cd " command too ).
- Use window file sharing. Not using it, but it is available as an option.
- Cloud file sharing (Onedrive/gdrive). A bit overkill, but does the job well.

4. "Use the Surface Book to send commands on the Main PC"

- I actually use anydesk.com app on handphone for this. they have special key (ctrl/Alt/Esc/PgUp/PgDn) keyboard included
- Bluetooth keyboard/mouse. Not really considered remote. But it does the job. (just to make it fancy, pair this keyboard to the surface, but sends the command via anydesk)
- Not a free solution, but It is the best 1 keyboard/mouse to multiple PC apps I've use. Ever. https://symless.com/synergy I used it when it was free, It IS good. In the same network (not though internet), configure the screen location (which one is left/right/center), then the Main PC mouse can 'jump' to the Surface. And Vice versa.

That's all I have. Hope it helps. In a way or another..
( :